# How to create a stack in main with integers values without making the size fixed

Tags: java, stack

```
static Stack<Integer> sort(Stack<Integer> s){
    Stack<Integer> auxiliar = new Stack<Integer>();
    int e;
    if(!s.isEmpty()) auxiliar.push(s.pop());
    while (!s.isEmpty()){
            e=s.peek();
            if(e>auxiliar.peek() && e<s.peek()) 
                    auxiliar.push(e);
            else if ((e>auxiliar.peek() && e>s.peek())|| (e<auxiliar.peek() &&      
            e>s.peek())){                                                    
                auxiliar.push(s.pop());
                s.push(e);
                s.push(auxiliar.pop());
        }
        else if (e<auxiliar.peek()&&e<s.peek()){
                s.push(auxiliar.pop());
                s.push(e);
        }
        else auxiliar.push(e);
    }
    return auxiliar;
}

void printStack(Stack<Integer> s){
    System.out.print("[");
    while (!s.isEmpty()){
         System.out.print(s.pop()+" "); 
    }
    System.out.print("]");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stack<Integer> a = new Stack<Integer>();
    a = {2,3,8,6,4};  //In this line I do not know how to give values to the stack.
    // I don't know if I have to make a function outside of main or if
    // I can do it like I was trying

    SortedStack element = new SortedStack();
    element.sort(a);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to add values to the stack is like:

```
    Stack<Integer> s = new Stack<>();
    s.addAll(Arrays.asList(2, 3, 4, 6, 4));
```

With this method, it will push in order from left to right, so 4 will be at the top of the stack and 2 at the bottom.